# Separate Favicon for Frontend and Backend

Tags: magento-2.2.5, favicons

So, I've located the file responsible for assigning the Favicon:

`vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/view/layout/layout.phtml`

Does anyone have a thought/suggestion on how to separate the Frontend and Backend Favicons? This is purely as a real-world QoL improvement that allows admins to quickly identify tabs when they have many open.

**EDIT:** So far, I've been able to build and apply a Backend Theme to apply my favicon. However, I'm still working on stopping the original favicon code from loading. As at the moment, this code is executed last so that's what the Browser sees.

**EDIT:** Swapping out the SVG with an ICO appears to have solved the issue.